# How to embed Powershell window into another wpf window or windows form?

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to embed powershell app into another wpf window or windows formm?

Or even a DOS propmpt shell?

Malcolm

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellTunnel

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but it seems the link in this answer no longer links to anything useful